# Prove that the set $A=\{S:S\subseteq \mathbb N,|S|\le 1\}$ is countable

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the set $A=\{S:S\subseteq \mathbb N,|S|\le 1\}$ is countable.

Hello everyone. I understand that this set is countable because it is equinumerous to $\mathbb{N}$. But I am not sure how to write a formal proof for this.

Comment: That is a finite set????

Comment: Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $S_n = \{n\} \in A$, thus $A$ is not a finite set because |$A$| $\geq$ |$S$|

Comment: The first thing I would do would be describe $S$ better.

Answer (score 5):

Since $S\subset\Bbb N$ and $|S|\le1$, you get that either $S=\emptyset$ or $S=\{k\},k\in\Bbb N$.

Thus
$$
A=\{\emptyset,\{k\}\;:\;k\in\Bbb N\}
$$
which is clearly countable (and NOT FINITE!!), since its elements are in bijection with elements of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that it is not finite. I got a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a finite set! $A$ is the collection of all sets that either have $0$ elements, or only have $1$ element. So $A$ consists of the emptyset $\varnothing$ and all singletons $\{n\}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e.
$$A=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\{n\}: n\in\mathbb{N}\} $$
You can count $A$, the first element is $\varnothing$, the second is $\{1\}$ the third is $\{2\}$ and so on. I believe you can write this enumeration explicitly by yourself!

Comment: Oops. I got the definitions mixed up somehow. I fixed it. Thanks for pointing that out.